# How to install Linux daemon using Kickstart

Tags: linux, kickstart

```
%post --log=/root/ks-post.log  --interpreter /bin/sh

exec < /dev/tty3 > /dev/tty3 2>&1
chvt 3    

cat > /mnt/sysimage/etc/init.d/daemon <<EOL
  #stuff goes here
EOL

chmod 755 /mnt/sysimage/etc/init.d/daemon 
ln -s /mnt/sysimage/etc/init.d/daemon /mnt/sysimage/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S09daemon 
chvt 1
```

The problem is that daemon does not exist in /etc/init.d/
and when I remove /mnt/sysimage prefix, kickstart freezes in post install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `/mnt/sysimage` directory in your freshly installed system.

Remember that [`%post` operates within the chroot environment](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-postinstallconfig.html), unless you explicitly tell it not to do so.

To resolve the problem, use the correct pathnames.